# how to break out of while loop with a mouse click in c++ on a mac?

Tags: c++, mouseevent

I am trying to break out of the while loop with a mouse click on a Mac. (not sure if it matters whether it's mac)
For example, if I have the following hypothetical piece of code:

```
int i=0;
while(true){
    // need an if statement here such as:
    // if(.....) break;
    // I don't know what conditional I should put into the if statement
    i++;
    cout << i << endl;  
}
```

How do I break out of it with a mouse click? I should use an if statement and some kind of event listener but I can't figure out the syntax. If there is a library I need to include please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Additional info: 
I am using the Stanford C++ libraries. and I tried the following:

```
    int i=0;
    while(true){
        GMouseEvent e = waitForEvent();
        if (e.getEventType() == MOUSE_CLICKED) break;
        i++;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
```

But what it does, is that it will wait and not execute the loop until it registers a mouse event. i.e. I have to move the mouse for it to execute the loop, as soon as I stop moving the mouse it waits again. It does break out of loop on click but it's still not the required behavior.

Comment: You have to indicate which framework/API are you using that can access operating system events. A mouse click rises an interrupt on the CPU then the operating system registers it.

Comment: On mouse click, set a boolean to true.. Your if statement should check that boolean to determine whether to break out.

Comment: I was going to ask _which_ mouse button you want to watch for, but then I saw "Mac" :)

Comment: Wow I haven't used that meme in decades (and I realise it's about as accurate as any other meme)